# Generate placeholders for numbers with random digits in sentence

Tags: python, regex, placeholder, substitution

### Problem

I need to create placeholders in a sentence (string).

#### Example

```
My son is 6 years old and my dad is 61 years old.
My son is #0 years old and my dad is #1 years old.
```

This is only one sentence. Sentences are separeted line by line and contains various positions in sentence for numbers and (number postions are mixed and differend length).

I have tried with various code but most of them works with pattern replacement.
I know the procedure and I could make it if I have been more experienced in python programming.

### Procedure

Read the sentence(line in text file). Count the number of numbers (d+) in sentence and then start replacing from the last number in sentence to the first (#6, #5, #4,...) if the sentence consists of 6 numbers.

#### For Example

```
My dog is 3 years old, 92.4 cm heigh and has 16 teeth.
```

Count the number of numbers with various lenght (1a,1b1,1c11,1111, 1.1 are 8 numbers): 4.

**1. loop** (replace 4th number):

```
My dog is 3 years old, 92.4 cm heigh and has #4 teeth.
```

**2. loop**:

```
My dog is 3 years old, 92.#3 cm heigh and has #4 teeth.
```

**3. loop**:

```
My dog is 3 years old, #2.#3 cm heigh and has #4 teeth.
```

**4. loop**:

```
My dog is #1 years old, #2.#3 cm heigh and has #4 teeth.
```

Add the line to the end of file and take another line from the file.
Repeat the steps until the end of the file.

Comment: Don't do this in regex. Also looks very much like homework, but regardless, don't do this with regex.

Comment: What language should it be? Why does the loop run backwards?

Comment: What happens if your string contains a literal #N, e.g. "son #1 is 6 years old". Should the literal "#1" be replaced/escaped, or just left in?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned python, you could do something like this:

```
import re

myStr = "My son is 6 years old and my dad is 61 years old."
expr = r'[^#][0-9]+'
idx = 1

while True:
    try:
        match = re.search(expr,myStr)
        print match.start()
        print match.end()
        print myStr[match.start():match.end()]
        myStr = myStr[:match.start()+1] + '#' + str(idx) + myStr[match.end():]
        idx += 1
    except AttributeError:
        break

print myStr
```